# Android - send sms in separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sms, google-cloud-messaging

I am writing an android application (with a service), where I need to send a message when I receive a GCM notification.

Main problem: When I send 3 SMS in same time, any other operation are stopped for a long time (10-20 seconds) and the phone is blocked, too. I tried to send SMS in thread, but there are no differences.

**SmsSender.java**

```
public class SmsSender implements Runnable{ 
    private Context context;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String message;
    private int id; 

public SmsSender(Context paramContext, String phoneNumber, String message, int id) {
        super();
        this.context = paramContext;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.message = message;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {    

        Intent sentIntent = new Intent("sent");
        Intent deliveredIntent = new Intent("delivered");
        sentIntent.putExtra("id", id);
        deliveredIntent.putExtra("id", id);
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, id,sentIntent, 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, id, deliveredIntent, 0);           

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();                    
        ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        sentList.add(sentPI);
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveredList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        deliveredList.add(deliveredPI);
        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentList, deliveredList);             

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Run thread**

> new Thread(new SmsSender(getApplicationContext(), phoneNumber,
>   message, id)).start();

Where is the problem? Why is the SMS sent in main thread, instead of my thread?

Comment: Try using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and create anonymous thread, such that it runs separately from your main thread. Refer [this](http://www.aviyehuda.com/2010/12/20/android-multithreading-in-a-ui-environment/) to know how to do it.

Comment: Agree with kush, use Handlers instead of the normal thread.

Comment: I think u work on ur design little bit . Can u please share design also ?

Answer (score 0):

As per android documentation

*What is a Service?

Most confusion about the Service class actually revolves around what it is not:
A Service is not a separate process. The Service object itself does not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part of.

A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).*

Comment: android application (with a service) .. i thought ur service is responsible for sending SMS via creating a new thread everytime

Comment: Yes, service is responsible. But I am creating new Thread in service.

Comment: y are u creating new thread just for sending SMS and that too within a service ..  When i have created a similar app .. i used listener to call my intent service which in turn send my sms .